# Twilio - should not reject incoming call when unregister device

Tags: twilio

Use case:
Twilio calling used both in web app and in mobile app.
There is incoming call - it is ringing both on mobile and in web app.

Current result:
when close tab in web browser it automatically rejects incoming call - it stops ringing on mobile.

Expected result:
it should be still ringing on mobile after closing tab with calling web app

Comment: Are the web browser and the mobile application registered as the same client identifier? Are you specifically rejecting the call beforeunload?

Comment: If client identifier means `token.identity` then yes - both web and mobile are registered as the same.
And no, I am not rejecting specifically. I can see that just `unregistered` event is triggered.

Comment: What happens if you reject the call from the browser? Does it also stop ringing on the mobile app?

Comment: Yes, it also stop ringing on the mobile app when I reject the call from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you reject a call to a client identifier, including by reloading the page, then the call is rejected for all versions of that client identifier across all applications.

To work around this, I would recommend using different identifiers for different devices and making simultaneous outbound calls to them, either with multiple [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client) elements if you are using TwiML or by starting multiple calls with the REST API. If you have to use the REST API, you should keep track of the calls so that once one connects you can end the others.

Comment: wouldn't it be nice to allow user choose if he want to reject call while unregistering device?